# How to keep sub select from disqualifying a set of id's

Tags: sql, subquery

I am at a loss of what direction to go here.
Here is what I am trying to do...
Imagine there is a "system" that has 5 boxes in it... each box has 10 pockets that can hold items. The database tracks inventory at a pocket level.
I need a list of itemid's where they are not anywhere in the parent "system" (given they still might be in pockets in other systems.

```
tblpocket
----------
systemid, itemid, pocketid, curqty
1,        PFLI,   12,       0      
1,        MEP50,  16,       0       
1,        PFLI,   20,       0       
1,        OND5,   32,       0       
2,        OXBUT,  10,       0       
2,        DIPL,   12,       0       
2,        OXBUT,  16,       1       
2,        PFLI,   18,       1
```

All but the "OXBUT" itemid need to be returned. Also you can see how doing a subselect to exclude where the itemid curqty > 0 would exclude it from the results altogether where it is stocked out on systemid 1.

I have 300 SystemID's and thousands of ItemID's so doing it systemid at a time is NOT an option.

Here is what I started doing:

```
SELECT systemid, itemid
FROM TblPocket
WHERE curqty = 0 AND itemid NOT IN
 (Select itemid from tblpocket where curqty > 0)
GROUP BY systemid, itemid
```

and THAT is where I get tripped up.... :(
Thanks for the ideas in advance :)

Comment: Anyone else have another take on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question . . . You are looking for items where curqty = 0 within a system.  However, an item could be in more than one pocket.  This seems a reasonable interpretation of "I need a list of itemid's where they are not anywhere in the parent "system" (given they still might be in pockets in other systems.".

This is an aggregation query:

```
select systemid, itemid
from TblPocket
group by systemid, itemid
having sum(curqty) = 0
order by systemid
```

However, your example with OXBUT suggests something a bit different:  items that are either all 0s or not ever 0.  This is a simple modification to the `HAVING` clause:

```
select systemid, itemid
from TblPocket
group by systemid, itemid
having sum(case when curqty = 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 0 or  -- all not zero
       sum(case when curqty > 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 0     -- all zero
order by systemid
```

Comment: Well... that still contains rows where the item is in another pocket in the system. If I take itemid off the SELECT and GROUP BY then I get the right number of rows...
So Maybe I do the having sum in a subselect somehow?? not sure how that would work..

Comment: Nope.. the max(case when) is still giving me back itemid's that are in other pockets inside the same system. (bang head here)

Comment: @user1040450 . . . That is intentional.  Your example excluded OXBUT but not PFLI.

Comment: Your max(case) is giving me OXBUT still... (that doesnt sound right...)

Comment: Is this the right criteria/syntax?
<code>having max(case when curqty = 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 0 or  -- all not zero<br>
max(case when curqty > 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 0     -- all zero</code>
Those two lines look the same to me... like "Having blah or (the exact same blah again)

Comment: The code is correct, although I changed it to a `SUM` from `MAX` for the explanation.  The first counts the number of times when curqty = 0.  If this is 0, then all are non-zero.  The second counts the numbers of times when curqty > 0.  If this is 0, then all are zero.

Comment: Nope. I still get all of the results.
I appreciate the effort. It just seems like there should be an easy way to tell SQL if group by system id and itemid, if itemid for a systemid > 0 then do not count.

I could do this with a for each loop in PhP.. why cant I figure an easy solution in SQL :(